# Different splash screen image for snapped view on Win8 store app

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps

I have defined the image in package.appxmanifest with

```
<SplashScreen Image="foo.png" BackgroundColor="#000000" />
```

but is it possible to define alternative image for snapped view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible.
But you can create "**fake splashscreen page**" that will be basically your page where you can put display one image for Fullscreen mode and other image for SnapView mode.
Similar behavior uses for instance the Store app where the actual splashscreen is shown only for a second and then you see page with green background, logo and ProgressRing.